# How can i display photo from the library?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using UIImagePickerController with source type UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary, the idea is i want to display the photo picked to full screen before the delegate will be called like using a navigationController to push to another view?

Comment: Just putting a question mark at the end of a stream of words doesn't make it a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change the behavior of delegate method. After you select the image from the camera roll, in the delegate method you can create a new view controller and shown it as modal. Then insert two button in this view controller:

1. the first, used for reject the image and open again the camera roll
2. the second, used for accept the image

For open again the camera roll, basically, you must call the open method again (i suppose this method is attached as target of a UIButton).